# Inconsistent behavior of git rebase --continue

Tags: git

Please get familiar with the two following simple use cases:

Use case #1 (rebase[`edit`] a commit, stage some changes and `--continue`):

```
___user___:/repo$ git rebase -i HEAD^^
Stopped at b4e8456...  Add commit #1
You can amend the commit now, with
  git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run
  git rebase --continue
___user___:/repo$ echo line >> file.txt
___user___:/repo$ git add file.txt
___user___:/repo$ git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto 5cf8c1e
Last command done (1 command done):
   edit b4e8456 Add commit #1
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   edit cfb1f47 Add commit #2
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '5cf8c1e'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   file.txt

___user___:/repo$ git rebase --continue
Stopped at cfb1f47...  Add commit #2
You can amend the commit now ...
```

Here we were able to stage changes and right after that `--continue` the rebase (without committing them). These changes don't affect the first edited commit but are in fact supplied to the successor commit (next one to edit) as part of its initial content.

---

Use case #2 (rebase[`edit`] a commit, `--amend` some changes, stage more changes and `--continue`):

```
___user___:~/repo$ git rebase --interactive HEAD^^
Stopped at 03fab68...  Add commit #1
You can amend the commit now, with
  git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run
  git rebase --continue
___user___:~/repo$ echo line >> file.txt
___user___:~/repo$ git commit -a --amend --no-edit
___user___:~/repo$ echo line >> file.txt
___user___:~/repo$ git add file.txt
___user___:~/repo$ git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto 5cf8c1e
Last command done (1 command done):
   edit 03fab68 Add commit #1
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   edit bfb5ff7 Add commit #2
You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '5cf8c1e'.
  (use "git commit --amend" to amend the current commit)
  (use "git rebase --continue" once you are satisfied with your changes)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   file.txt

___user___:~/repo$ git rebase --continue
error: You have uncommitted changes in your working tree. Please, commit them first and then run 'git rebase --continue'.
```

In this case however we got an error. The only difference is that in the meantime we amended some stuff to the first commit. But from the `git status` point of view the processing phase is exactly the same and I don't see a sensible reason why would Git treat these cases differently.

Does Git's mechanism distinguish those for some deliberate reason or is it actually kind of a bug (unintended inconsistency)?

`git version 2.25.1`

Comment: In the posted transcript, it is suspicious in the first case that the rebase completes without stopping after the first `--continue` even though that you have marked the second commit with `edit`, too. Please clarify whether your transcript is genuine.

Comment: @j6t You're right, thanks. I mixed lines from different trials during preparations for the question. Anyway, the transcript corrected and retested. The question stays valid.

Answer (score 2):

I would call this an "unintended inconsistency". I say this because I have observed the following:

1. In the latter case, the error is not based on a state change, but instead on the current commit ID getting changed. If you simply change the commit ID (e.g. using `--amend --no-edit`) without changing the state you *still* get the error. The only way you don't get the error is if the commit ID *that was just created* remains intact.
2. When attempting `cherry-pick` with staged changes you get a similar error in *both* scenarios.

Comment: While this may indeed be "unintended", I suspect that the makers of Git would dismiss a request to remove the "inconsistency" with the argument that it acts as a safeguard against PEBKAC errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. Regarding `cherry-pick` you mean a `cherry-pick --no-commit` to stop before it's applied and then test the `--continue` behavior, right (just to ensure)?

Comment: @bloody actually no. If you cherry-pick with `--no-commit` it doesn't "pause" the cherry-pick in the middle so `--continue` isn't even available. Cherry-pick `--continue` is for when you have a conflict during the cherry-pick, and in that case `--continue` writes the currently staged files into the commit, unlike with rebase where `--continue` starts working on the *next* commit. To simulate working on the next commit like with rebase, you would just use the regular cherry-pick. (The error messages are different though so it's obviously not functionally identical behind the scenes.)

Comment: @bloody btw, the reason I even tried comparing the behavior with `cherry-pick` is because conceptually rewriting commits with rebase should be similar (if not identical) to doing it with cherry-pick. The fact that cherry-pick doesn't allow any staged files ever, but rebase allows a staged file only if the previous commit ID did not change, seems inconsistent to me. IMHO it would make more sense if all 4 scenarios never allowed it, or always allowed it.

Comment: @j6t Currently, in 1 out of 4 of the presented scenarios it doesn't error. If they (Git maintainers) consider it a PEBKAC error to have something staged before rewriting a commit, then perhaps they should make it consistent and block it in all cases.

Comment: @TTT The one case is where a commit is `edit`ed, and then `rebase` is `--continue`d without changing the head commit in the interim. If that would stop here with an error, that would certainly be considered a major regression, because that is the majority of use-cases for tagging a commit with `edit`. (*I* would be upset.)

Comment: @j6t what you just described wouldn't error. The error is if you do that *and* stage a new file before continuing the rebase. This question is only about the inconsistency of having something staged before rewriting a commit.

Comment: @TTT Sorry, I did not mention it, but I do actually mean that changes were also staged before `--continue`.

Comment: @j6t OK. Then if you would be upset if it errored there, why wouldn't you also be upset if you amended the head commit before staging a file for the next commit? Because now it suddenly errors.

Comment: @TTT Oh, I *am* upset at that time. But only slightly, because it reminds me that I deviated from the road that `rebase` prepared for me.

Comment: @j6t With rebase you are almost always deviating from the original road. I just clarified in the answer: Git writes a brand *new* commit ID. 1 second later you change that new commit ID to something else (with no state change) and now you get the error. If you leave the commit ID you don't get the error. That seems inconsistent